# Changing Eclipse's server IP address

Tags: eclipse

I want to change the IP address of my server manualy using Eclipse (in order to work with Android mobile devices). I found this page: [local android network](http://juristr.com/blog/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your/).

But it says that I have to go to run/configuration under arguments(x), but i didn't find it on my Eclipse. Would you tell me where to find it?

Comment: I think you should take a step back and describe what task specifically you're trying to accomplish. _Why_ do you want to change your IP? What's wrong with the one(s) you've already got? Over which interfaces do you want that IP to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the dialog you are looking for by clicking on `Run` menu, `Run Configurations...` submenu, and then on the `Arguments` tab. You can also click on the following button on your toolbar (and then on `Run Configurations...` and `Arguments`):

[image]

Don't forget to select the project or class you are intending to run and/or configure before clicking `Ok` or `Apply`.